# CSS manipulation using buttons

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make a small settings page where users can change how the site looks, I want them to be able to click a button and the sites CSS update along with it (along with the background colo(u)r) and I would like the changes saved across all pages.

How would I do this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  Unfortunately, this question is a bit broad for the site-- instead of asking for an answer to a specific question, it asks for a suggestion on how to implement an entire _feature_ for your site.  I think it will be difficult for anyone to provide you with meaningful guidance here (although I invite the community to prove me wrong).  You may with to review [ask] and [help/on-topic].  Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your question, I have come up with a solution that suits your use case better in a neater implementation.

Take the following code for example;

```
<div id="container">
 <div>
  <h1>Page Header</h1>
  <h3>Page Sub Header</h3>
  <p>Page Content</p>
 </div>

 <div class="buttons">
  <button id="default-theme" onclick="setTheme(event)">default</button>
  <button id="theme-one" onclick="setTheme(event)">theme one</button>
  <button id="theme-two" onclick="setTheme(event)">theme two</button>
 </div>
</div>
```

In the code above, you have some unstyled elements and some buttons to set the preferred theme color.

You can set the theme colors like below in your CSS file. The code below is an SCSS implementation. Check out the live solution on codePen https://codepen.io/sirwhite/pen/mdbNjLG

```
<style>
 // Default theme color

 .default-theme {
  background: $default-bg;
 }

 .default-theme h1 {
  color: $default-color;
 }

 .default-theme h3 {
  color: $default-color;
 }

 .default-theme p {
  color: $default-color;
 }

 // Theme One Colors
 .theme-one {
  background: $theme-one-bg;
 }

 .theme-one h1 {
 color: $theme-one-color;
 }

 .theme-one h3 {
  color: $theme-one-color;
 }

 .theme-one p {
  color: $theme-one-color;
 }

 // Theme Two Colors
 .theme-two {
 background: $theme-two-bg;
 }

 .theme-two h1 {
  color: $theme-two-color;
 }

 .theme-two h3 {
  color: $theme-two-color;
 }

 .theme-two p {
  color: $theme-two-color;
 }
</style>
```

Now, use javascript to set the theme color based on the user's selection

```
var theme = '';
var container = document.getElementById('container');

window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  if(localStorage.theme && localStorage.theme !== '') {
    theme = localStorage.theme;
    container.classList.add(theme);
  }
  else {
    theme = 'default-theme';
  }
});

function setTheme(event) {
    theme = event.target.id ;
    localStorage.theme = theme;
    container.classList = [];
    container.classList.add(theme);
}
```

You can use LocalStorage to persist the selected theme value across all pages. When the page loads, you can check if localStorage value is set else set the theme to the default theme.

Check out the live solution on codePen https://codepen.io/sirwhite/pen/mdbNjLG

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with javascript or jquery by calling a function when your button is clicked.

Our HTML, notice how we call `myFunction` when we click on the button.

```html
<h1 class="item blue">Hello World</h1>

<button onClick="myFunction()">Click Me</button>
```

Some basic CSS:

```css
.blue {
  color: blue;
}
.red {
  color: red;
}
```

Our Javascript will add a class depending on what class is already present. We can change our target variable to add/remove classes from a different element.

```
function myFunction() {
  var target = document.querySelector('.item');

  if (target.classList.contains('red')) {
    target.classList.remove('red')
    target.classList.add('blue')
  } else if (target.classList.contains('blue')) {
    target.classList.add('red')
    target.classList.remove('blue')
  }
}
```

This is a very cookie-cutter way of doing this, but it works and you can take the same principles here and apply it to your code.

To use this site-wide, just use a seperate javascript file and import the same javascript and call the same function on each page.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score -1):

As per my understanding of the question you want to  change the background colour on the button click

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
  .yellows {
    background: yellow;
  }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<button id="btn">click me </button>
<script>

$('#btn').click(function() {
  $('body').toggleClass( "yellows" );
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```